# How to insert array field in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.6

How can I insert multiple input radio data with Laravel?

When I select a radio button and click submit form to insert into my database

Here is my html:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered  table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th bgcolor="#DFF0D8">
        <h5>
          <b>
            <center>Question No</center>
          </b>
        </h5>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#DFF0D8">
        <h5>
          <b>
            <center>Yes</center>
          </b>
        </h5>
      </th>
      <th bgcolor="#DFF0D8">
        <h5>
          <b>
            <center>No</center>
          </b>
        </h5>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="question1">
        <h5>1.You Like It's
        </h5>
      </td>
      <!-- true checkbox Q1 -->
      <td>
        <div class="flat-green single-row">
          <div class="radio ">
            <center>
              <input name="q1[]" type="radio" value="1">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flat-green single-row">
          <div class="radio ">
            <center>
              <input name="q1[]" type="radio" value="0">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="question2">
        <h5>2.you don't like it's
        </h5>
      </td>
      <!-- true checkbox Q2 -->
      <td>
        <div class="flat-green single-row">
          <div class="radio ">
            <center>
              <input name="q2[]" type="radio" value="1">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="flat-green single-row">
          <div class="radio ">
            <center>
              <input name="q2[]" type="radio" value="0">
            </center>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My QuestionController.php :

```
$question = new Question;
$question ->id = $request->get(id);
$question ->question_no = 'question1';
$question ->score = $request->get('q1');
$question ->save();
return redirect('/questionForm/create');
```

But it can insert to database only one row and I want to insert data to database table like this:

```
|id|user_id|question_no|score|
|1 |  1    | question1 |  1  |
|2 |  1    | question2 |  0  |
```

How to insert multiple data to database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple data means you have to insert multiple times. `$request->get('q1')` and `$request->get('q2')` both produce arrays so you have to loop over them (or `array_sum()`, or whatever you need to do to aggregate your q1/2 values to a single `score` column).

Now, assuming `score` is the sum of the checked values, and `id` is an autoincrement column it would look something like this:

```
    // deal with the q1 array
    $q1_array = $request->input('q1');
    $question = new Question;
    foreach ($q1_array as $q1_answer) {
        // i'm assuming table.score is the sum of the values of the arrays
        $q1_total =+ $q1_answer;
    }
    $question->question_no = 'question1';
    $question->score = $q1_total;
    $question->save();

    // now deal with the q2 array
    $q2_array = $request->input('q2');
    $question = new Question;
    foreach ($q2_array as $q2_answer) {
        // i'm assuming table.score is the sum of the values of the arrays
        $q2_total =+ $q2_answer;
    }
    $question->question_no = 'question2';
    $question->score = $q2_total;
    $question->save();
```

Of course this was written only for clarity. You could have a separate loop outside so you don't repeat the question1 and question2 code.

Here is a more abbreviated version, assuming your table is named `answers`:

```
    DB::table('answers')->insert([
        ['user_id' => $userId, 'question_no' => 'question1', 'score' => array_sum($request->input('q1'))],
        ['user_id' => $userId, 'question_no' => 'question2', 'score' => array_sum($request->input('q2'))],
    ]);
```

Comment: How I can get text id in tag td <td id="question1"> you have solution ?

Comment: oh, data in `<td>` tags are not passed during POST, so you have to put them in `<input type="hidden">` tags.